# Getting test results when creating a Karma server programmatically

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to run multiple Karma test files in parallel from inside a Node script and get to know which tests are passing or failing. Right now what I have is this:

```
const exec = require("child_process").exec;
exec("karma start " + filename, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    // handle errors and test results...
});
```

The code above works well, and I can get the information on tests passed or failed from stdout. However, it requires having installed Karma and all of the associated dependencies (reporters, browser launchers, etc.) globally. I am looking for a solution that doesn't require me to install all dependencies globally.

My first thought was this:

```
const karma = require("karma");
const server = new karma.Server(config, () => {
    // some logic
});
```

However, when trying this other approach, I have been unable to gather the test results programmatically.

When using new karma.Server(), is there any way in which I could know which tests have passed or failed (and, ideally, a stack trace of the error)? Alternatively, is there any other way in which I can execute my tests and get the desired information programmatically without the need to install dependencies globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, changing the exec line to this seems to do the trick:

```
exec("node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start " + filename, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
```

It turns out I'd only need to run the locally installed version of Karma instead of the global one. :-)